# Save rows where column value changes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have `DataFrame` which has 5 columns and many rows. I want to store only every changed values or drop every unchanged values. Below there I show you what I have.

```
column1          column2          column3          column4          column5
      1             cat1            name1                n            time1
      1             cat1            name1                n            time2
      1             cat1            name1                n            time3
      1             cat1            name2                n            time4
      1             cat1            name1                n            time5
      1             cat1            name2                n            time6
      1             cat1            name1                n            time7
      1             cat1            name3                n            time8
      1             cat1            name3                n            time9
      1             cat1            name3                n            time10
      1             cat1            name3                n            time11
      1             cat1            name4                n            time12
```

and I want only rows where column3 values are changing like this

```
column1          column2          column3          column4          column5
      1             cat1            name1                n            time1
      1             cat1            name2                n            time4
      1             cat1            name1                n            time5
      1             cat1            name2                n            time6
      1             cat1            name1                n            time7
      1             cat1            name3                n            time8
      1             cat1            name4                n            time12
```